# How can I Integrate ln(x² - x + 2) dx?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to do this in so many ways but I can never find something solid. Please help me. I have used the integrate by parts theorem calling u = ln(x² -x + 2) and dv = dx, but in the end I find something unclear.

Comment: In what way is this question related to *Mathematica*?

Comment: Wrong site, try http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

**Comment**

Apparently, this question is not related to *Mathematica* or any other computing software but, I will give you a step by step evaluation of the integral in maple, to which you can compare your try.

For this purpose, I have used the package `Student[Calculus1]`.

```
restart:
with(Student[Calculus1]):
ShowSolution(Int(ln(x^2-x+2),x));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica*:

```
Integrate[Log[x^2 - x + 2], x]
```

$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log \left(x^2-x+2\right)-2 x+\sqrt{7} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2
   x-1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)$